# extract string between a string using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `https://twitter.com/xyz/profile_image?size=normal`.

I am trying `let trimmedUrlRE = fullUrl.match("(https:\/\/twitter.com\/).*(\/.*)")` to get the **xyz** but I am not getting it in trimmedUrlRE array.

Please help.

Comment: [`https:\/\/twitter\.com\/([^\/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/cEE8T0/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URL` constructor, `.slice()`, `.split()`, `.shift()`

```
var url = new URL("https://twitter.com/xyz/profile_image?size=normal");
// get `.pathname` beginning at index `1`, split `"/"`, shift array
var pathname = url.pathname.slice(1).split("/").shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your regex slightly

```
var match = fullUrl.match(/(?<=(https:\/\/twitter.com\/)).*(?=\/)/g);
var output = match ? match[0] : "";
```

Explanation

- `(?<=(https:\/\/twitter.com\/))` matches but doesn't capture till **.com/**
- `(?=\/)` matches but doesn't capture succeeding `/`